# The Grails path is not saving

Tags: linux, grails

I have installed Grails on Linux and set my Grails_HOME and JAVA_Home paths likes:

```
[Hbrock@Harrison-Oracle ~]$ export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0
[Hbrock@Harrison-Oracle ~]$ export PATH="$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin"
[Hbrock@Harrison-Oracle ~]$ export GRAILS_HOME=/home/Hbrock/Grails/grails-2.2.0.RC1
[Hbrock@Harrison-Oracle ~]$ export  PATH="$PATH:$GRAILS_HOME/bin"
[Hbrock@Harrison-Oracle ~]$ javac -version
javac 1.6.0_24
[Hbrock@Harrison-Oracle ~]$ grails -version
Grails version: 2.2.0.RC1
```

But it does not seem to be saving this. I this is error the next time I open the terminal widow and try to run grails:

```
[Hbrock@Harrison-Oracle ~]$ grails -version
bash: grails: command not found
[Hbrock@Harrison-Oracle ~]$
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've only set those paths for the current terminal session. You would need to add those commands to your shell's startup file.  Since you're running some flavor of linux, it might be

```
~/.bashrc
```

Do an `ls -a` and look for that file (or something similar) and then add all the commands you entered at the command line.  Then, every time you start your shell/terminal, they will be set.

Comment: Am running Oracle Linux which is base off of Redhat

Answer (score 3):

Open the current user's env file and add all in that.

For example: If you are using Ubuntu then steps would be like this:

1. Open a terminal
2. open the bashrc file by
     either `vi ~/.bashrc`
     or     `gedit ~/.bashrc`
3. go to the last line
4. add

   `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0`
   `export GRAILS_HOME=/home/Hbrock/Grails/grails-2.2.0.RC1`
   `export PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:$GRAILS_HOME/bin:$PATH"`
5. save the file
6. run 
   resource ~/.bashrc
   it will refresh the current terminal env
   or you can close the current terminal and open a new

Note: I have written

```
export PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:$GRAILS_HOME/bin:$PATH"
```

instead of 
`export PATH="$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$GRAILS_HOME/bin"`

because, if anyone has more than one java installation then the folder come first in the $PATH will be used.

Hope it will clear you all steps